# How to return an error bean of validation with a list of invalid attributes for Rest service with spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I have a Rest server developed with spring boot, I need to return an error report for the attributes format errors (invalid date, invalid integer, invalid string, object instead of a array, ..)

The problem is, in case of invalid parameters in the sent json object, we must return an object with a list of {field, errorMsg}

Example

```
{
  "message": "Invalid request parameters",
  "properties_errors": [
    {
      "property": "mail",
      "cause": "Email format invalid"
    },
    {
      "property": "startDate",
      "cause": "Date format invalid"
    }
  ]
}
```

In the controller, I annotated the object to validate, given as parameter, with @Valid @RequestBody MyObj obj
After that I have foud two solutions:

1. Custom Deserializers

Define custom Deserializers (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer) that convert from String or Object value of the json object to the desired type
of the entity attribute and annotate these attributes with @JsonDeserialize (using = MyCustomDeserializer.class).

The problem with this solution is that it fails at the first error (only one attribute error to be returned).
Spring uses **HttpMessageConverter** to convert the http request body to the entity object, the spring implementation in our case is **MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter** that uses a **jackson** **Objectmapper**, which uses a **com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer** that fails on first error of deserialization with IOException and after that will be enveloped by the MessageConverter in **HttpMessageNotReadableException**

This method seems more cleaner but I do not know if we can redefine the ObjectMapper or the BeanDeserializer to fail with a root exception report containing all the attributes with problems

1. DTO for entities

A second solution is to define DTO objects to be used in the controller (instead of the entities) where all the attributes are of type Object, and after the creation of this object (let spring and jackson create this dto) we make validation of these attributes (with specific **javax.validation.ConstraintValidator** that check whether the DTO attributes of type Object are instanceOf our desired type)

This second solution gives the desired end result because it uses the API validation of spring which already gives an **MethodArgumentNotValidException**. But it's very ugly to have DTO with attributes of type Object for the validation and then convert them to the correct model for the business layer, it is not generic, ...

Is there a better solution or approach that I missed for such a result

Answer (score 4):

I have not tested the below with your scenario but I believe a similar solution can be used.

Using @ControllerAdvice handle the exception with @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class). Get all error results and then return a list of objects containing the validation errors. Example below.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerValidationHandler {
    @Autowired
    private MessageSource msgSource;

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ValidationMessages processValidationError(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        BindingResult result = ex.getBindingResult();
        List<FieldError> fieldErrors = result.getFieldErrors();
        return new ValidationMessages(fieldErrors.stream()
                .map(fieldError -> processFieldError(fieldError))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

    private ValidationMessage processFieldError(FieldError error) {
        ValidationMessage message = null;
        if (error != null) {
            Locale currentLocale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
            String msg;
            try {
                msg = msgSource.getMessage(error.getDefaultMessage(), null, currentLocale);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                msg = error.getDefaultMessage();
            }

            message = new ValidationMessage(error.getField(), msg, MessageType.ERROR);
        }
        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes of course, if we can have the exception MethodArgumentNotValidException with all invalid fields, it is clear how to make a response but my question was how to get this exception